# How to change "localhost" to app name in Google Identity Toolkit API SMS verification?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, recaptcha, google-identity-toolkit

I'm using the Google Identity Toolkit API on my backend to generate a reCAPTCHA sitekey using the [getRecaptchaParams](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/getRecaptchaParams) endpoint. I pass the `recaptchaSiteKey` to the front end, which is built with Vue Ionic. The front end then uses this sitekey to generate a reCAPTCHA and obtain the `recaptchaToken`. This token is then sent back to the backend to be used in the [sendVerificationCode](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/sendVerificationCode) endpoint. However, the SMS message received by the user displays the following:

```
276025 is your verification code for localhost.
```

I would like to know how to change "localhost" to the app name. I added the domain to the Authorized Domains list in the Firebase Console and removed "localhost" from the list. However, I encountered the following error:

```
CAPTCHA_CHECK_FAILED : Hostname match not found
```